# Transform a list of dataframes to a nested dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I'm struggling with this problem:

I have three lists of dataframes (each list has the same number of rows, each dataframe has 3 columns). I want to combine the lists into one nested dataframe, such that there are 3 columns (one column for a list).

Sample code:

```
a_list_of_dfs <- lapply(seq_along(a_list), function(i) {
  
  tibble(x = a_list[[i]]$x,
         y = a_list[[i]]$y,
         z = a_list[[i]]$z)
})

b_list_of_dfs <- lapply(seq_along(b_list), function(i) {
  
  tibble(x = b_list[[i]]$x,
         y = b_list[[i]]$y,
         z = b_list[[i]]$z)
})

c_list_of_dfs <- lapply(seq_along(c_list), function(i) {
  
  tibble(x = c_list[[i]]$x,
         y = c_list[[i]]$y,
         z = c_list[[i]]$z)
})

nested_df <- tibble(a=a_list_of_df,
                    b=b_list_of_df,
                    c=c_list_of_df)
```

The problem is, this solution doesn't give me the result I want. The idea is to be able to access the nested dataframe like this:

```
nested_df$a$x
```

How can I change that to get the result I want?

Edit:
`a_list`, `b_list` and `c_list` are nested lists where each element has some string attributes. For example, `a_list` has X rows and each row has attributes `name`, `label` and `value`. So I want to achieve a solution where I can just access the nested dataframe like this:

```
nested_df$a$name  # and value etc.
```

The result of the `dput` function below (kept only the first two elements, the strcture is the same across a list):

```
`list(structure(list(name = "VS", label = "VS", 
    value = "SUM"), .Names = c("name", 
"label", "value")), structure(list(name = "VP", 
    label = "VP", value = "SUM"), .Names = c("name", 
"label", "value")),`
```

**My solution**
Passing a dataframe instead of a list of 1-row dataframes as a column worked for me.

Comment: Can you add an example of the contents for `a_list`, `b_list` and `c_list`?

Comment: @Freguglia Just added more information.

Comment: You will need to actually provide the result of `dput(a_list)` in your solution. The way I see it, `nested_df` is a three column df, with columns a,b,c, where each column is a list of tibbles.  The elements of list `nested_df$a` are unnamed, so `nested_df$a$name` probably is returning NULL for you.

Comment: @langtang I added the result. When I try to, for example, access it like `nested_df$a$name` it doesn't work but when I do `nested_df$a[[1]]$name` then it does

Comment: exactly. because the elements of the list of tibbles in `nested_df$a` are not named. They can be accessed using `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, etc.  Each of those (unnamed) elements is itself a dataframe, with named columns such as `name`, `value`, `label`, etc.. which you can acess as you do above (i.e. `nested_df$a[[1]]$name`)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your data is not very clear because your sample is a bit small.  But does this do what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)  
df <- list(structure(list(name = "VS", label = "VS", value = "SUM"), 
                     .Names = c("name", "label", "value")), 
           structure(list(name = "VP", label = "VP", value = "SUM"), 
                  .Names = c("name", "label", "value")))

df <- df %>% set_names(c("a", "b"))

df$a$name
df %>% as_tibble()
```

You should name the list elements.

Comment: Not quite. The dput result shows two list elements (there are hundreds of elements). What I want to achieve is to, since all elements in that lists are tibbles, I want each of the elements to become a single row and each list to become a single column. So let's say each list has 100 elements, the output dataframe should have 100 rows and 3 columns since there are 3 lists.